# Capacitive Discharge

Tags: capacitor

With capacitors being used in different parts of the automobile, such as in conjunction with audio equipment, what is the correct way to discharge them in order to prevent personal injury?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know two ways, depending what the equipment is:

1) to allow sufficient time for self-discharge, usually stated by the manufacturer when dealing with the high energy ignition circuits,

2) for the large audio power capacitors then to discharge them through a power resistor of about 4k ohms...

Comment: How does one go about #2? #1 seems pretty obvious ... you just wait the specified time.

Comment: Professionally designed equipment should have the resistors to automatically discharge the caps already built in. Leaving such resistors permanently connected has no effect on the operation of the device and they only cost a few cents. If you don't trust that, switching on the device *after disconnecting the power supply* will usually discharge the caps. Otherwise, you have to bridge the cap terminals with the resistor for a few seconds, which runs the risk of giving yourself a shock by touching both terminals of the capacitor at the same time.

Comment: Once the car battery (or batteries) are disconnected, then using the resistor connect between the cap’s live side and earth - **carefully**, otherwise you get to be part of the circuit.... :) shocking...

Comment: The way **not** to do it is to short circuit the cap terminals with a screwdriver or something similar. In extreme cases, that will produce a big spark, a loud bang, *and vaporize part of the screwdriver blade* - been there done that, back when I was a teenager and didn't know better!

Comment: I’ve got a screwdriver like that :) ...

Comment: It's worth adding the warning that large electrolytic capacitors (which physically look like cylindrical cans, several mm in diameter and height) can "spontaneously recharge" because some electrical charge gets "hidden" in the chemical reactions inside the cap, and "emerges" again in a timescale of minutes or hours. So if you have a cap that you removed from some equipment and it has been sitting on a shelf for a week, *don't assume it is discharged* even if you are sure that you personally discharged it before you removed it.